# Botão de cancelar em um timer

Tags: python, python-3.x

Olá, eu estava fazendo um timer que ia até 100 e depois para, e então tive a brilhante idéia de colocar um botão de cancelar a contagem. Eu fiz umas coisas só que quando ele fala "Para cancelar digite "c"" o timer não continua até que eu dê alguma resposta.

Tem como fazer o timer continuar em vez de esperar por uma resposta ?

```
import time
porcentagem = 1
vitima = input('Quem deseja hackear?')


def main():
    while True:
        time.sleep(1)
        global porcentagem
        porcentagem = porcentagem + 1
        if porcentagem < 100:
            global hackeando, vitima
            hackeando = 'a'
            hackeando = input('Hackeando {}, {} %, Para cancelar digite "c"'.format(vitima,porcentagem))
            main()
        elif porcentagem == 100:
            print('Hackeado com sucesso')
        elif hackeando == 'c':
            break


main()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Tem como fazer o timer continuar`  - "ter como, tem". Só que isso deixa de ser um programa simples como o que você está fazendo, e sobretudo, viola a forma esperada de funcionamento de programas pelo terminal.

Tentando explicar melhor: quando você esta fazendo um programa que só se comunica com o usuário com `print` e `input` (ou mesmo usando outras funções, mas sobretudo, usando o terminal ("cmd" no windows)) - a regra é que para o programa, tudo o que ele vai "receber" do usuário (com a função "input") é indistinguível para o programa de um arquivo texto que ele vai *ler* linha a linha. Só que o sistema operacional só vai realmente passar para o programa (quer esse use o input, quer ele esteja lendo o "arquivo do terminal" de alguma outra forma) uma linha inteira de cada vez - e uma linha só é considerada quando o usuário apertar "enter". 
Então - tanto o input, quanto a leitura do arquivo de outra forma, só consegue ler, ou saber se o usuário digitou qualquer coisa, quando ele pressiona enter. Esse "arquivo de entrada" pode ser configurado de forma diferente, mas não só isso é muito mais avançado do que programas que usam `print` e `input`, nessa faase de aprendizado, como o comportamento do programa fica estranho pra usuários acostumados com programas no terminal.

Em geral, quem usa programas no terminal - mesmo programas avançados usados por desenvolvedores, como o `git`, **não** respondem a teclas sem parar a execução e ficar aguardando o usuário. A interrupção do programa é feito pela combinação de teclas `ctrl + C`.

## Como Criar um Programa com Maior interação com o Usuário

Se você pretende evoluir a interação com o usuário, o ideal é começar a aprender a criar programas que ou criem uma janela gráfica, usando por exemplo, o [tkinter](http://www.dsc.ufcg.edu.br/~pet/jornal/setembro2014/materias/tutoriais.html), ou aplicações Web, usando um framework como o [Flask](https://flask-ptbr.readthedocs.io/en/latest/).

Vale mais a pena do que tentar mudar o comportamento de um programa do terminal, antes de ter um bom domínio de programação.

Um programa mais sofisticado do terminal pode usar a biblioteca `curses` por exemplo, mas também é um outro nível de programação - pode dar mais trabalho do que aplicações gráficas simples usando o tkinter, e serem muito mais estranhas para o usuário final.

## Mas eu queria muito fazer no terminal, só esse aqui

Existe uma forma mais simples do que reconfigurar o terminal para detectar teclas avulsas, mas que envolve uma mudança para um outro paradigma de programação. (aplicações Web ou gráficas vão envolver uma mudança parecida de qualquer forma).
 Nesse caso, você teria que mudar o seu programa para ele usar duas "threads" em paralelo. Uma "Thread" é basicamente isso: o seu programa "se divide" e passa a ser executado de forma paralela - o Python vai efetivamente, do ponto de vista do desenvolvedor, estar executando duas ou mais linhas ao mesmo tempo. então enquanto uma thread pode estar parada aguardando o resultado do "input", a outra pode continuar com o timer.

Criar threads é fácil - mais difícil nesse caso é controlar a saída do terminal, se você estivsse imprimindo a contagem regressiva. Programas "reais" usando threads podem ser bastante complexos, por conta de dados que são alterados em uma thread e modificam o comportamento do programa em outra (tanto é que há uma tendência a não se usar threads, há vários anos).

Por fim, se colocarmos apenas o "input" em uma thread separada, o timer pode continuar correndo na thread principal - e em cada passo você observa se o usuário mandou que o programa parasse.

Nesse programa simples, ao final da contagem, o programa se encerra - como o `input` vai estar rodando, o programa vai ficar parado esperando o usuário apertar `<enter>` de qualuer forma. Não há como forçar a parada de uma thread que esteja esperando um `input` - então essa abordagem não funcionaria em qualquer programa mais complexo.

```
import time
from threading import Thread

porcentagem = 0
vitima = input('Quem deseja hackear?')


def verifica_parada():
    global parada
    while True:
        entrada = input("Pressione 'c' e <enter> para cancelar")
        if entrada == 'c':
            parada = True
        return

def main():
    global porcentagem
    thread_de_parada = Thread(target=verifica_parada)
    thread_de_parada.start()
    while True:
        time.sleep(1)
        porcentagem +=  1
        if parada:
            print("Programa cancelado pelo usuário")
            return
        if porcentagem < 100:
            print (f'Hackeando {vitima}, {porcentagem}%, Para cancelar digite "c" e <enter>')
        elif porcentagem == 100:
            print('Hackeado com sucesso')

parada = False
main()
```

Fiz algumas outras melhorias no programa que podem contribuir para seu aprendizado - `global` só é necessário para as variáveis que você vai alterar na função, e deve vir sempre no início da função.

Outra coisa é que você estava chamando a função "main" recursivamente de dentro dela mesma - não há a menor necessidade disso nesse caso - o comando `while` já repete o bloco principal do programa dentro de `main`.